# Xcode 4, Can I split the Project Navigator?

Tags: xcode4, project, navigator

In Xcode 3 I can easy to split any window.
And usually I would split my project navigator (the editor bar on the left).
Can I still split the project navigator in Xcode 4?

Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

That feature no longer exists as of Xcode 4.