# Can I split 'Xcode project navigator' from main window?

Tags: xcode, navigator, project-navigator

I want use Xcode project navigator by floating option like many other editors.
For example, Android studio support many view modes like Dock pinned/Dock unpinned/Undock/Floating/Window. I used this option very useful with multi monitors.

How can I split Xcode project navigator?
Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems that it's not possible to do this anymore, at least in Xcode 4: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080753/xcode-4-can-i-split-the-project-navigator